# c++ getting a random number, within a probability

Tags: c++

Is there any function in C++, that helps me creating a number between a range with a given probability?
E.g. a number between 1 - 10, with a result that the number is 20% between 1 -3 and 30% between 4 - 7 and 40% between 7 and 10?

I found this one, but it seems, it only fits for specific number, not numbers within a range...

```
double val = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

int random;
if (val < 0.05)       //  5%
    random = 0;
else if (val < 0.25)  //  5% + 20%
    random = 1;
else if (val < 0.55)  //  5% + 20% + 30%
    random = 2;
else
    random = 3;
```

Comment: Side note, for C++ use the <random> header if you want better quality random numbers. There are some distribution models for you to use too

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you want to do, please. Your probabilities (20%+30%+40%) only add up to 90% and it is unclear whether you want an integer or floating-point result.

Comment: C++ have had a lot better functionality for [pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than the old C `rand` function.

Comment: *"it only fits for specific number"* -- Think more abstractly. This code handles the weighting, giving you specific **cases**. In this code, there is a 30% case for the value `2`; in your functional requirements, there is a 30% case for a value between 4 and 7. So if you were to replace the `2` with a function that returns a value between 4 and 7, what would happen?